# Magento 2 Register and login REST API

Tags: php, rest, magento, magento2, magento-2.3

I'm creating an app for magento2 with Rest API. I'm facing the below issues.

Im able to create the user through REST  API

```
auth Berear token : bbiotqwwj04prtja2oum5gvfsqt8dnjh

API : Register 

URL : http://demo-acm-2.bird.eu/rest/all/V1/customers
method : POST
Request Body 

  {
     "customer": {
         "email": "pradeep123@gmail.com",
         "firstname": "Abc",
         "lastname": "Xyz",
         "storeId": 1
     },
     "password": "Qwe@123123"
  }


Response 

{
    "id": 3,
    "group_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2020-04-18 12:30:40",
    "updated_at": "2020-04-18 12:30:40",
    "created_in": "Default Store View",
    "email": "pradeep123@gmail.com",
    "firstname": "Abc",
    "lastname": "Xyz",
    "store_id": 1,
    "website_id": 1,
    "addresses": [],
    "disable_auto_group_change": 0,
    "extension_attributes": {
        "is_subscribed": false
    }
}
```

But when I try to login with the same user to get token it gives me a message like an error. Is there any other way to get a user token/login with rest api in magento2

```
    API: Login

URL: http://demo-acm-2.bird.eu/rest/all/V1/integration/customer/token
method : POST
Request Body

{
    "username" : "pradeep123@gmail.com",
    "password" : "Qwe@123123"
}

Response 

{
    "message": "You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled."
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Customer Registration API**

**API Name:** Customer Registration API

**Description:** Create customer account. Perform necessary business operations like sending email.

**API URL:** {baseurl}/rest/V1/customers

**Method:** POST

**Body:**

```
{
        "customer": {
            "email": "testtest123@gmail.com",
            "firstname": "Kavin",
            "lastname": "Peter",
            "addresses": [{
                "defaultShipping": true,
                "defaultBilling": true,
                "firstname": "Kavin",
                "lastname": "Peter",
                "region": {
                    "regionCode": "NY",
                    "region": "New York",
                    "regionId":43
                },
                "postcode": "10755",
                "street": ["123 Oak Ave"],
                "city": "Purchase",
                "telephone": "1234567890",
                "countryId": "US"
            }],
            "extension_attributes": {
                "is_subscribed": true
            },
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code": "customer_mobile",
                    "value": "1234567890"
                 }
            ]
        },
        "password": "test123"
    }
```

**Response:**

```
{
    "id": 55,
    "group_id": 1,
    "default_billing": "32",
    "default_shipping": "32",
    "created_at": "2020-08-29 12:10:14",
    "updated_at": "2020-08-29 12:10:31",
    "created_in": "Default Store View",
    "email": "testtest123@gmail.com",
    "firstname": "Kavin",
    "lastname": "Peter",
    "store_id": 1,
    "website_id": 1,
    "addresses": [
        {
            "id": 32,
            "customer_id": 55,
            "region": {
                "region_code": "NY",
                "region": "New York",
                "region_id": 43
            },
            "region_id": 43,
            "country_id": "US",
            "street": [
                "123 Oak Ave"
            ],
            "telephone": "1234567890",
            "postcode": "10755",
            "city": "Purchase",
            "firstname": "Kavin",
            "lastname": "Peter",
            "default_shipping": true,
            "default_billing": true
        }
    ],
    "disable_auto_group_change": 0,
    "extension_attributes": {
        "is_subscribed": true
    },
    "custom_attributes": [
        {
            "attribute_code": "customer_mobile",
            "value": "1234567890"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Login API**

**API Name:** Login API

**Description:** Create access token for the customer credentials.

**API URL:** {baseurl}/rest/V1/integration/customer/token

**Method:** POST

**Body:**

```
{
        "username": "kirti.nariya@magedelight.com",
        "password": "test@$123"
    }
```

**Response:**

```
"bdw1x6cb3ntbdj6d4pqfzr8xksjezkv2"
```

Answer (score 0):

{
"username": "testtest123@gmail.com",
"password": "test@$123"
}

Note - please change the password in registration Data (prepared curtomer data)

And getting Response

"eyJraWQiOiIxIiwiYWxnIjoiSFMyNTYifQ.eyJ1aWQiOjMsInV0eXBpZCI6MywiaWF0IjoxNjg4NzE3ODM4LCJleHAiOjE2ODg3MjE0Mzh9.kxW97_7xqG48pVjlWI3Dla-gazGTdQNSmLdxyfd2tBg"

Comment: is this an answer?